# Generating large html table with mysql query very slow - 4000+ rows query

Tags: html, mysql

The table is created more than 3 minutes after I send a request database tables in the database has about 4000 records, I think it could be solved via JavaScript but I'm not sure how. thanks

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM tblRazduzeniUgovori";
 if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $query)) {
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
     {
           echo "<tr>";
           echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='brojUgovora[]' value='" . $row['Broj'] . "'/></td>";
           echo "<td style='font-size:15px;'>" . $row['Broj'] . "</td>";
           echo "<td>" . $row['Kontrolni_Broj'] . "</td>";
           echo "<td><span class='label label-success' style='width:90%;'>";
           foreach ($kor_id as $key => $val) {
                    if ($val == $row['Korisnik_ID']) {
                        echo $kor_ime[$key] . " " . $kor_prezime[$key];
                        break;
                        }
                    }
           echo "</span></td>";
           echo "<td>" . $row['Datum_Razduzenja'] . "</td>";
           echo "<td>" . $row['Ime_Kupca'] . "</td>";
           echo "<td>" . $row['Ime_Prodavca'] . "</td>";
           echo "<td>" . $row['Cijena'] . " KM</td>";
           echo "<td style='padding:6px;'><span class='label label-         info' style='width:90%; text-align:center;'><a href='/crm/ugovori/" . $row['Slika'] . "' style='color:white;'>" . $row['Slika'] . "</a></span></td>";
           echo "</tr>";
     }
     }
  mysqli_close($con);
  return $vrati;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

first reduce your query to only ask for the fields you want for your table, e.g:

```
$query = "SELECT Broj,Kontrolni_Broj FROM tblRazduzeniUgovori "
```

(Obviously add the rest of the fields you need to the select)

second use concatenation, rather than tonnes of echoes.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tblRazduzeniUgovori";
$output = '';
 if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $query)) {
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
     {
           $output .= "<tr>";
           $output .= "<td><input type='checkbox' name='brojUgovora[]' value='" . $row['Broj'] . "'/></td>";
           $output .= "<td style='font-size:15px;'>" . $row['Broj'] . "</td>";
           $output .= "<td>" . $row['Kontrolni_Broj'] . "</td>";
           $output .= "<td><span class='label label-success' style='width:90%;'>";
           foreach ($kor_id as $key => $val) {
                    if ($val == $row['Korisnik_ID']) {
                        $output .= $kor_ime[$key] . " " . $kor_prezime[$key];
                        break;
                        }
                    }
           $output .= "</span></td>";
           $output .= "<td>" . $row['Datum_Razduzenja'] . "</td>";
           $output .= "<td>" . $row['Ime_Kupca'] . "</td>";
           $output .= "<td>" . $row['Ime_Prodavca'] . "</td>";
           $output .= "<td>" . $row['Cijena'] . " KM</td>";
           $output .= "<td style='padding:6px;'><span class='label label-         info' style='width:90%; text-align:center;'><a href='/crm/ugovori/" . $row['Slika'] . "' style='color:white;'>" . $row['Slika'] . "</a></span></td>";
           $output .= "</tr>";
     }
     }
  mysqli_close($con);
    echo $output;
  }
```